# Using regex in Javascript to match special symbols

Tags: javascript, regex

I am developing a web application for a school.  They have terms like `course_name` and `class_name`.  Think of a course as a template for a class, meaning that a class must inherit most attributes of a course.

Now, the `class_name` MUST contain the `course_name`.  For example: if course_name is "CSS" then the class_name can be "CSS 101" or "Beginning CSS".  Checking for this is easy using regular expressions.  I used to use word boundaries \b\b.

However, I recently ran into an issue where the user typed "HTML (Beginner)" as the `course_name`.  \b being a word boundary will no longer work in this case to find a match in the `class_name`.  Can someone please help me on this?  My brain is exploding thinking of all the possibilities.  The solution should cover most, if not all, scenarios.

-Mark

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear in my last paragraph.  Using word boundaries on "HTML (Beginner)", like so:  new RegExp("\\b"+course_name+"\\b") doesn't work because of the parenthesis.  If no parenthesis was present, then the regular expression would have been flawless...

Answer (score 0):

```
var courses = "HTML (Beginner)".match(/\w+/g);//gives ["HTML", "Beginner"];
if (courses)//can be null if no word chars found
  for (var i = 0; i < courses.length; i++)
    //look for course[i] in your list of courses
```

Comment: Like I mentioned above.  There are class_names and course_names and class_names MUST ABSOLUTELY contain every single character found in course_names.  Doing /\w+/ would only match the words...  My question is:  How would I match the parenthesis together with the word as well?

Answer (score 0):

You can use 'one or more spaces' as a word separator to extract words and then do a compare right ?

var courses = "HTML (Beginner)".match(/[^\s]+/g); //gives ["HTML", "(Beginner)"]

Answer (score 0):

First, you'll need to be able to regex-escape the course name.  I'm using the code from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3561493/is-there-a-regexp-escape-function-in-javascript):

```
course_name.replace(/[-\/\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}]/g, '\\$&')
```

In order to simulate boundaries when the first/last character in `course_name` might not be word characters, use the following:

```
RegExp("(?:^|\\W)" + str + "(?:$|\\W)")
```

At the beginning, we check for either the beginning of the string or a non-word character, and at the end either the end of the string or a non-word character.

Putting these together, we have:

```
RegExp("(?:^|\\W)" + course_name.replace(/[-\/\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}]/g, '\\$&') + "(?:$|\\W)")
```